# How to reorder columns of large sparse matrix in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, reshape

How to reorder columns of sparse matrix of class dgCMatrix. For the dataframe it goes this way:

```
data_frame<-data_frame[c(2,1,3:ncol(data_frame))] #reorder first two columns, as in original data
```

When I try to do with sparse_matrix_data:

```
sparse_matrix_data<-sparse_matrix_data[c(2,1,3:ncol(sparse_matrix_data))]
```

It gives `Error in asMethod(object) : Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105`

Yes it is due to large sparse matrix. However other operation, like deleting one particular column named "id", did not give any error. I believe deletion or reordering both are simple operation.

```
sparse_matrix_data<-sparse_matrix_data[, !(colnames(sparse_matrix_data) %in% c("id"))]
```

gives no error.

Comment: Deleting or reordering columns in a sparse matrix is not trivial. A sparse matrix generally consists of two vectors: One with the non-zero entries an another integer vector that defines the positions of the elements within the matrix. I would not change a thing in a sparse matrix. It is probably much easier to create a new sparse matrix without the columns that you want to omit.

Comment: Actually I have to correct myself: A sparse matrix usually consists of three vectors, and not of two: one which stores the non-zero values and two integer vectors used for the indexing. But that doesn't make things easier.